# How to delete and alter in mysql event scheduler?

Tags: mysql

My sql script is like this :

```
CREATE 
EVENT `deleteEvent`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 30 MINUTE STARTS '2016-03-23 00:00:00'
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE
ENABLE
DO
DELETE FROM hotel;
ALTER TABLE hotel AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

I don't using truncate. Because, there is error like this :

```
Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint.........
```

So, I using Delete and alter

But, when using delete and alter, it's not working

Any solution to solve my problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try: so you can use TRUNCATE if clear both Tables. After Truncate the Auto_inc is also 1

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
TRUNCATE FROM hotel;
TRUNCATE FROM ConstraintsTable;
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

You can set more queries like this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
    DO
    BEGIN
      SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
      TRUNCATE FROM hotel;
      TRUNCATE FROM ConstraintsTable;
      SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
    END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: In mysql event scheduler, only run 1 query

Comment: @moses toh - i have add a sample in my answer

Comment: update you answer. truncate no need `from`. so, like this : `TRUNCATE hotel`